# CMake: How to use LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY?

Tags: cmake, fortran, intel-mkl

Linking against the Intel MKL static libraries introduces circular dependencies. When I import the libraries,

```
set(LIBRARIES mkl_intel_lp64 mkl_sequential mkl_core)
foreach(_lib ${LIBRARIES})
  add_library(${_lib} UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(${_lib} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/lib${_lib}.a)
endforeach()
```

and link to my executable,

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${LIBRARIES})
```

I get a ton of undefined references to the linear algebra calls. For example,

```
ztrevc3_gen.f:(.text+0x1af7): undefined reference to `mkl_blas_zdscal'
```

One way to get around this is to use the appropriate linker flags:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE -Wl,--start-group ${LIBRARIES} -Wl,--end-group)
```

Another option is to do this:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${LIBRARIES} ${LIBRARIES} ${LIBRARIES})
```

However, as I was searching for a more elegant solution I came across the `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY` property. If set this property along with the imported library location,

```
set(LIBRARIES mkl_intel_lp64 mkl_sequential mkl_core)
foreach(_lib ${LIBRARIES})
  add_library(${_lib} UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(${_lib} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/lib${_lib}.a
    LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY 3)
endforeach()
```

I get the same undefined references as before, so appearently this is not working. What is the proper way to use LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY and is there a more elegant way to get around circular dependencies?

**EDIT**

Here is a minimal example that fails, this time with the correct `IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY` variable.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(test Fortran)
add_executable(main main.f90)
set(LIBRARIES mkl_intel_lp64 mkl_sequential mkl_core)
foreach(_lib ${LIBRARIES})
  add_library(${_lib} UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(${_lib} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/lib${_lib}.a
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY 3)
endforeach()
list(APPEND LIBRARIES dl pthread)
target_link_libraries(main ${LIBRARIES})
#target_link_libraries(main ${LIBRARIES} ${LIBRARIES} ${LIBRARIES})

# main.f90
  call zpotrf
end program
```

If you uncomment the last line then the build succeeds. Unfortunately, the MKL in not free (except in some cases) but hopefully somebody can test this. I should note that it fails with some linear algebra calls and not others like `dgemm`.

Answer (score 0):

Property [LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY.html) is for "normal" *STATIC* library. For *IMPORTED* library [IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY.html) property should be used instead:

```
  set_target_properties(${_lib} PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/lib${_lib}.a
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY 3)
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get undefined references. I'll try to create a minimal example and get back to you.

Comment: @RaulLaasner: Can you create that minimal example? I'm facing a similar problem right now...

Comment: @einpoklum See the edit in the question. I think that example shows that `IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY` is not working as it should. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @einpoklum More discussion on the topic here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17964